# Para que se usa el Group Join de Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, linq

```
WLista = (From T In obj
          Group Join P In .PassWord
                On P.Numero Equals T.PassWord
                Into Pw = Group From P1 In Pw.DefaultIfEmpty
          Group Join A In .Atributo
                On A.Empresa Equals T.AtributoEmpresa And
                   A.Numero Equals T.AtributoNumero
                Into At = Group From A1 In At.DefaultIfEmpty
```

Comment: Deberías desarrollar mas tu pregunta,no solo lanzar un trozo de código. Que es lo que no entiendes exactamente? Que es un `Group Join`? Tienes algún problema con el código que has pegado?

Comment: Si, el problema es que no lo puedo enlazar otra tabla para que traiga datos.

Comment: En ese caso amplia tu pregunta especificando cómo es la otra tabla y que problema tienes al enlazarlo. Lo mejor en estos casos es tratar de hacer un [mcve] de tal manera que el que te quiera ayudar pueda probarlo en su equipo. [Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/queries/group-join-clause) tienes una explicación sobre que hace Group Join, pero entiendo que no es esa la repuesta que quieres.